# How to use CustomEventData in Button component Cocos Creator 3.5.0 Typescript

Tags: cocos2d-android, cocoscreator

In the `Button` component we have `CustomEventData`. In my understanding the purpose it to send extra parameter when user tap the button.

[image]

I have tried to use it like this:

```
use_powerUp(par: string){
    console.log("MapScreenManager::use_powerUp() = ", par);
}
```

The `Button` will call the function and I thought the `CustomEventData` will be automatically become 1 parameter that will fill the par parameter. But turns out it didn’t.

Can anyone guide me how to properly use the CustomEventData?

I am using Cocos Creator 3.5.0 with Typescript.

Answer (score 2):

I just found the solution, it's very simple

```
use_powerUp(event: Event, CustomEventData)
{

}
```